# how to implement 'on_click' method for c# graphical objects

Tags: c#, drawing

```
int Y = 20;
for (int row = 0; row <= 19; row++)
{
    int X = 25;
    for (int col = 0; col <= 29; col++)
    {
        Graphics graphicsObj;
        graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();
        graphicsObj.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, X, Y, 5, 5);
        X += 25;
    }
    Y += 20;
}
```

Hi 
I added some graphical object by using `Drawing` (like above code).
what i need to do, is, if i click on them i need to know on which object i clicked. 
so i want to get their name when i click on them. on other hand i need to implement `on_click` or 'on_mouse_move' method for them.
 how do i do it?

Comment: As you are drawing directly on a canvas, there are no 'objects' to click on except for the canvas, therefore any click handling will have to be handled by yourself (or some other library that you find).  You could create UserControl object for each shape you draw, but finding where you clicked is going to be up to you to determine.

Answer (score -1):

Use a picture box :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int Y = 20;
            for (int row = 0; row <= 19; row++)
            {
                int X = 25;
                for (int col = 0; col <= 29; col++)
                {
                    PictureBox box = new PictureBox();

                    Graphics graphicsObj = box.CreateGraphics();
                    graphicsObj.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, X, Y, 5, 5);
                    X += 25;

                    box.Click += new EventHandler(Box_Click);


                }
                Y += 20;
            }

        }
        private void Box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you write in method `private void Box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` ?

Comment: You need to add the box to the main form.  This.Controls.Add(box);